# Symfony2 - Application with multiple modules

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I'm building Symfony2 application that will have 3 different "modules" - first for user trying to translate text from one language to another, second for translators and third for admin. I'm wondering what will be the best app structure for this.

Should I have:

- three bundles UserBundle, TranslatorBundle and AdminBundle
  or
- have bundles for functionality like translations and divide user/translator/admin access withing such bundles.

What is the best possible approach? I couldn't find any good article on the web covering this topic.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony website has some great articles on this subject:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

Generally speaking though, don't agonise over it. Symfony is very flexible, so you can always restructure later down the line without too much pain. In my personal experience, I've always put things into separate bundles too soon and made extra work for myself because I have to keep hopping between bundles to achieve a (relatively) simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Matt is right. Sometimes even single Bundle is enough for all your needs. Unless you are sharing your bundles across different applications.

I think you need to have `admin` bundle separate. Othwise you end up with double the number of bundles one for frontend and one for backend. just set the `firewall` for admin section.

have a look at this
[What should a bundle in Symfony2 represent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770753/what-should-a-bundle-in-symfony2-represent)