# What is Bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, bundle

So I recently started to learn Symfony2 and came up on a term called Bundle.... I didn't understande to clearly the definition of that in the tutorail.. So if some can explaine me, give some definition it would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770753/what-should-a-bundle-in-symfony2-represent

Comment: Brief addition: Unless you are developing shippable bundles for use in other projects, you will generally have all of your code in a single bundle. Symfony's best practices offer more details on this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should everything really be a bundle in Symfony 2.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-in-symfony-2-x)

Comment: @cristian, That's not necessarily true. Sometimes as project get bigger it's nicer to have individual block of work in separate bundle so that they can clearly be developed on their own. I (although I may be alone on this) find it easier to work with a "MessageBundle" that is self contained and then merge via a "CoreBundle" rather than a "WebsiteBundle" that has everything that I have ever done peppered throughout.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Symfony2 conceptual issue: general bundles vs. specific ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012191/symfony2-conceptual-issue-general-bundles-vs-specific-ones)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770753/what-should-a-bundle-in-symfony2-represent/